# How do I ignore HTTPS errors for devices in playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I am writing playwright tests and testing them on my local machine, which has SSL but the cert is often giving errors.

I want to ignore all HTTPS-related errors when developing on my local machine. (I will do final testing in the cloud with a valid cert.)

For browsers, you can add `ignoreHTTPSErrors` to `contextOptions` like this:

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Safari MacBook Air',
      use: {
        browserName: 'webkit',
        viewport: {
          width: 2560,
          height: 1620,
        },
        contextOptions: {
          ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        },
      },
    },
```

However, I can't find a similar option for `devices`:

```
{
  name: 'iPhone 6/7/8',
  use: devices['iPhone 8'],
},
```

How can I ignore HTTPS errors with a device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't actually tried, but as I see it, can't you use it as well in your mobile project?

For example, in your config:

```
    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    {
      name: 'Mobile Chrome',
      use: {
        ...devices['Pixel 5'],
        contextOptions: {
          ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
        },
      },
    },
```